# Classes and constructors

Tags: php, oop

For getting some default options, there is the following class:

```
class settings { 
    function __construct() {
        $this->companyName = "Company x"; /* retrieving information from the database */
    }
    function getCompanyName() { return $this->companyName; }
}
```

Of course, this class has other important functions, but for simplifying this question; this class get the settings from the MySQL database.

Now, there is another class for sendings some mails.

```
class mailing extends settings {
    function __construct() { /* Default options for mailing */ }
    function sendMail() {
        echo "Send mail to ".$this-> getCompanyName();
    }
}
```

I would like to get the settings from the class `settings`, but without calling `parent::__construct()` in this class since the information is already retrieved from the database in the settings class. I call the systems as following:

```
$settings = new settings();
$mailing = new mailing();
$mailing->sendMail();
```

Unfortunately, I didn't get the company name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually it seems very strange to me that `mailing` is an instanceof `settings`.

I think this makes more sense:

```
$settings = new Settings();
$mailer = new Mailer($settings);
$mailer->sendMail();
```

Then you can either have the `Mailer` copy all the values from the `Settings` class or keep the `Settings` class as a store for your values:

```
class Mailer {
    public function __construct(Settings $settings) {
        $this->companyName = $settings->get("companyName");
    }
    public function sendMail() {
        echo "Send mail to: " . $this->companyName;
    }
}
```

or

```
class Mailer {
    public function __construct(Settings $settings) {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }
    public function sendMail() {
        echo "Send mail to: " . $this->settings->get("companyName");
    }
}
```

---

This approach allows you to put some validation in the constructor of `Mailer` to check if it has received all the `Settings` (by means of `$settings->has("X")`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `parent::_construct()`, otherwise the statements in the constructor of the `settings` class will not be run.

Constructor of the `mailing` class should look like this:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::_construct(); // General settings set by settings constructor
    // Mailing specific settings like already done in the current constructor
}
```

Comment: Ok, but the 'problem' is that the system is getting the information again from the database, isn't it?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. Obviously, it would spare some resources if you used the same DB connection for the two constructors (it could be done by initializing the connection in the constructor of the mailing class and passing it to the constructor of its parent).

Answer (score 0):

In your example `$settings` and `$mailing` are different instances so there is nor relation between them. If you don't want to call parent construct you can do something like this:

```
$settings = new settings();
$mailing = new mailing();
$mailing->companyName= $settings->companyName;
$mailing->sendMail();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just perform a simple trick with `if` statement in the constructor and constructor parameter stating if the script should load the data from DB or the data is already there and there is no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it this way then you have to find a method to set company name at mail class , for example

```
class mailing extends settings {
function __construct($company_name) { $this->companyName = $company_name; }
function sendMail() {
    echo "Send mail to ".$this->companyName;
}
}
```

and this part of code should be

```
$settings = new settings();
$mailing = new mailing($settings->getCompanyName ());
$mailing->sendMail();
```

Comment: That is an option, but I have to pass multiple variables so this isn't the best solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

whether you're NOT doing anything in the mailing construct you can even miss it. Otherwise you have to call parent construct first and then write your code.

Example:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::_construct(); 

    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending a class would not help you achieve what you are trying to do, and i am not sure if this is the best design. However if you want to have an object with all the settings and then have a mailing class that uses this options, you should do it by adding a property "settings" to the mailing class:

//your settings class:

```
class settings { 
    function __construct() {
        $this->companyName = "Company x"; /* retrieving information from the database */
    }
    function getCompanyName() { return $this->companyName; }
}
```

//new mailing class, constructors takes a settings object

```
class mailing {

    private $settings;

    function __construct(settings $settings) { 
        $this->settings=$settings;
    }

    function sendMail() {
        echo "Send mail to ".$this->settings->getCompanyName();
    }
}
```

//initialize the settings from DB

```
$settings = new settings();
```

//create new class with initialized settings

```
$mailing = new mailing($settings);
$mailing->sendMail();
```

This will output "Send mail to Company x" and you can reuse the settings object where you may need it.